# In Simon's algorithm, why is $f$ one-to-one if (and only if) $s=0^n$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simons-algorithm

I'm dealing with Simon's algorithm a bit and "stumbled" upon something called for the algorithm. It is said that if the period is $s = 0^n$, then it is an injective function, that is, a 1 to 1 function. How can you show that this is so?

Then I would be interested. Moreover, if that is not the case, so $s \neq 0^n$, then why is it a 2 to 1 function?

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the definition of the type of function that you apply Simon's algorithm to. You are required to have a function $f(x)$ such that
$$
f(x)=f(y)
$$
*if and only if* $x\oplus y=0$ or $s$.

Hence, if $s$ is all zeros, the outcomes are all unique: if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y\oplus 000\ldots 0$, but bitwise addition modulo with 0 doesn't change the bit values, so $x=y$.

On the other hand, if $s$ is non-zero, there are exactly two values that give the same value of $f(x)$ since $x\oplus00\ldots 0=x$, just leaving the distinct $y=x\oplus s$.

---

To add, following a comment. I suspect we need to go further back and understand the notation better. There is a function $f(x)$. It accepts, as an argument, a sequence of $n$ bit values, which we write as a variable $x$ (we write $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ as a shorthand for conveying it's made up of $n$ bit values). The answer is a sequence of $n$ bit values, which we write as $y=f(x)$. We are promised that $a$, also a sequence of $n$ bit values exists such that
$$
f(x)=f(x\oplus a).
$$
The calculation $x\oplus a$ has a very specific meaning; we take each bit of $x$ (call the $i^{th}$ bit $x_i$) and each bit of $x$ and return the sequence where they have been added together modulo 2:
$$
x_i\oplus a_i=x_i\text{ XOR }a_i=x_i+a_i\text{ mod }2=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & x_i=a_i \\ 1 & x_i\neq a_i\end{array}\right.
$$
So, for example
$$
00110\oplus 01010=01100.
$$
A key feature of this bitwise addition function is that
$$
x\oplus a\oplus a=x.
$$

---

An example of a suitable $f(x)$ is
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
x & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 110 & 111 \\
f(x) & 010 & 011 & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 000 & 001
\end{array}
$$
Here, you can see that each value of $f(x)$ is repeated exactly twice. So, we find two values of $x$ that give the same output, say $001$ and $101$. These correspond to values $x$ and $x\oplus a$, so we can find $a$ with
$$
a=x\oplus(x\oplus a)=001\oplus101=100.
$$
Then you can check for every $x$ that $f(x)=f(x\oplus 100)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe I should clarify something, what I mean. I found this in a lecture: $ f(x) = f (x \oplus a) $ (That's understandable for me, I think of the real sine with $+2\pi$ and without). Now it comes: $ x, y \in \{0,1\}^n, \text{if } x \neq y \oplus a, \text{ then } f(x) \neq f(y) $ this part is not understandable to me, what does that say? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I suspect there's something you've misunderstood, and we haven't yet stepped far enough back to unpick what the problem is. Where does the sine function come into it?

Comment: The sine does not have to do with that at first, only when I think of a periodic function, I first think of the sine. For this applies yes: $sin(x)=sin(x+2\pi)$. And starting from the sinus example, I could think of this as well: $f(x)=f(x\oplus a)$
 
My problem was simply because I also found this in a lecture, which was not completely understandable for me:$x, y \in \{0,1\}^n, \text{if } x \neq y \oplus a, \text{ then } f(x) \neq f(y) \text{ "Eq: 1"}$ I can follow your explanation. Unfortunately this does not answer my implicit question: See "Eq: 1"